# ImageLoader and loading images from app's resources

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

Is this possible to use Universal ImageLoader for drawables inside my app's resources instead of url? I mean something like this, but with drawable:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);
```

Edit:

I want to include it into adapter so it will get less laggy... Code below is not working, but at least you will know what I had in my mind.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.champion_list, null);

        holder.txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img);

        v.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        // View recycled !
        // no need to inflate
        // no need to findViews by id
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt.setText(web[position]);
    //holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    String imageUri = "drawable://" + imageId[position];
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, holder.img);

    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt;
    ImageView img;
}
```

Comment: What does imageId refer to? IDs in R.drawable.* ?

Comment: It is an int array of drawables

Comment: And what happens when you do `holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);` ?

Comment: LogCat shows this, so i haven't configured imageloader. - "imageloader must be init with configuration before using" , but when i use `imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this))` i get error because adapter is noit an activity.

Comment: Then re-define your adapter to get an extra parameter which will be the context (ie your activity will call it with whatever parameters you already give him + `this`), store this context, and init your image loader with 
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext))

Comment: This made it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want ?

```
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, this should suit you :

```
holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working...  (The method setImageResource(Integer) is undefined for the type ImageLoader)